# MongoError $in needs an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i am using trying to get data from an array and want to pass it to my find query inside $in operator.
But its giving an error saying

> $in needs an array

```
const fileIds = _.get(result, 'files', []);
console.log(fileIds);
db.collection('files').find({_id: {$in: fileIds}}).toArray((err, files) => 

{
    // some statements....
}
```

here is the output of console.log(fileIds)

> { '0': 5a8f24ab281bd22cd940530b, '1': 5a8f24ab281bd22cd940530c }

before marking to duplicate i have seen this post.

[How to return the ObjectId or _id of an document in MongoDB? and error "$in needs an array"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557580/how-to-return-the-objectid-or-id-of-an-document-in-mongodb-and-error-in-need)

but these aren't helping. so if anyone knows the answer please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So the `fileIds` is object, not array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Please do this
>
> here i have use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) which is supported by node version 6.9
>   or 8 you can create array by another method

```
  const fileIds = _.get(result, 'files', []);

    db.collection('files').find({_id: {$in: Object.values(fileIds)}}).toArray((err, files) => 

    {
        // some statements....
    }
```

Comment: thanks bro. it saved me a lot of time. Still i did a lot of research.. but thanks again