# how to remove an object from json

Tags: javascript

**I want to remove '_id' from below json ?**

```
var json = {'@Version': '0', 'AirReservation': {'AirItinerary': {'OriginDestinationOptions': {'OriginDestinationOption': {'@RefNumber': '0', '@DirectionId': '0', '@ElapsedTime': '0320', 'FlightSegment': {'@DepartureDateTime': '2018-04-09T05:30:00', '@ArrivalDateTime': '2018-04-09T07:20:00', '@FlightNumber': '873', '@ResBookDesigCode': 'V', '@Status': 'HK', 'FlightDuration': '2018-04-03T03:20:00', 'DepartureAirport': {'@LocationCode': 'IKA', '@Terminal': ''}, 'ArrivalAirport': {'@LocationCode': 'IST', '@Terminal': 'I'}, 'OperatingAirline': {'@Code': 'TK'}, 'Equipment': {'@AirEquipType': '332'}, 'MarketingAirline': {'@Code': 'TK'}, 'BookingClassAvails': {'BookingClassAvail': {'@ResBookDesigCode': 'V', '@ResBookDesigQuantity': '9', '@RPH': 'ADT', '@AvailablePTC': 'ADT', '@ResBookDesigCabinCode': 'M', '@FareBasis': 'VLY1PXOW'}}}}}}, 'PriceInfo': {'ItinTotalFare': {'BaseFare': {'@Currency': 'TRY', '@Amount': '521.00'}, 'MarkupFare': {'@Amount': '0'}, 'TotalFare': {'@Amount': '569.04', '@Currency': 'TRY'}, 'TotalAmountInTicketingCurrency': {'@Amount': '569.04', '@Currency': 'TRY'}}, 'PTC_FareBreakdowns': {'PTC_FareBreakdown': {'PassengerTypeQuantity': {'@Code': 'ADT', '@Quantity': '1'}, 'PassengerFare': {'BaseFare': {'@Amount': '521.00'}, 'MarkupFare': {'@Amount': '0'}, 'Taxes': {'Tax': {'@Amount': '48.04'}}, 'TotalFare': {'@Amount': '569.04'}}, 'TicketDesignators': {'TicketDesignator': [{'@TicketDesignatorCode': '70|PEN', '@TicketDesignatorExtension': 'TICKETS ARE NON-REFUNDABLE|'}, {'@TicketDesignatorCode': '41|LTD', '@TicketDesignatorExtension': 'LAST TKT DTE|09APR18| - DATE OF ORIGIN|'}]}}}, 'ServiceFees': {'ServiceFee': {'@Amount': '0', '@MarkupFeeAmount': '0', 'PassengerTypeQuantity': {'@Code': 'ADT', '@Quantity': '1'}}}}, 'TravelerInfo': {'AirTraveler': {'@PassengerTypeCode': 'ADT', 'NumberOfBaggages': '0', 'NumberOfBaggages1': '0', 'HandLuggages': '0', 'HandLuggages1': '0', 'PersonName': {'NamePrefix': 'MRS', 'GivenName': 'dd', 'Surname': 'ff'}, 'Telephone': {'@PhoneType': 'Home', '@LocationCode': '_+98091_2366554'}, 'Email': 'testss@gmail.com', 'Document': [{'@DocID': 'T12312233', '@DocType': 'DOCS', '@InnerDocType': 'Passport', '@ExpireDate': '2018-04-03', '@DocIssueCountry': ' 1002247'}, {'@DocIssueLocation': '', '@DocID': '1234567891236', '@DocType': 'DOCO', '@DocIssueCountry': ' 1002247'}, {'@DocType': 'DOCA', '@DocIssueCountry': ''}, {'@DocType': 'DOCA2', '@DocIssueCountry': ''}], 'BirthDate': '1996-05-02'}}, 'Fulfillment': {'PaymentDetails': {'PaymentDetail': {'@PaymentType': 'None', '@PaymentFPType': 'FPCA', 'BillingAddress': {'AddressLine': 'hbuyh hjgb hj hjgyg', 'CityName': 'Tehran', 'CountryName': {'@Code': 'IR'}}}}, 'DeliveryAddress': {'AddressLine': 'Iran Tehran', 'CityName': 'Tehran', 'CountryName': {'@Code': 'IR'}}}, 'Ticketing': {'@TicketTimeLimit': '2018-04-05T23:59:00', '@TicketType': 'BookingOnly'}, 'BookingReferenceID': {'@Type': 'F', '@ID_Context': 'QKC86K'}, 'FlightRulePenalties': {'FareRuleInfo': {'FareReference': 'VLY1PXOW', 'FilingAirline': {'@Code': 'TK'}, 'MarketingAirline': {'@Code': 'TK'}, 'DepartureAirport': {'@LocationCode': 'THR'}, 'ArrivalAirport': {'@LocationCode': 'IST'}, 'FareRules': {'SubSection': {'@SubTitle': 'PENALTIES', '@SubCode': 'PE', 'Paragraph': {'Text': 'FOR ROUND TRIP INSTANT PURCHASE FARES\n\n CHANGES\n\n ANY TIME\n CHARGE USD 50.00 FOR REISSUE/REVALIDATION.\n NOTE -\n A-BEFORE DEPARTURE-\n ITINERARY MUST BE RE-PRICED USING CURRENT FARES\n IN EFFECT ON THE DATE THE TICKET IS REISSUED\n THE ITINERARY MUST MEET ALL RULE PROVISIONS OF\n THE NEWLY TICKETED FARE INCLUDING ADVANCE\n RESERVATION\n -\n CHARGE APPLIES PER TRANSACTION - PER PERSON FOR\n ADULT CHILD AND INFANT WITH SEAT.\n INFANTS WITHOUT A SEAT ARE NOT CHARGED THE FEE\n -\n FOR TR DOMESTIC SECTORS- WITHOUT CHARGE\n -\n NEW FARE MAY BE EQUAL OR HIGHER. WHEN THE NEW\n ITINERARY RESULTS IN A HIGHER\n FARE THE DIFFERENCE WILL BE COLLECTED AND THE\n CHANGE FEE WILL BE APPLIED.\n -\n CHARGES SHALL NOT BE WAIVED FOR MEDICAL\n REASON\n -\n WHEN FARES ARE COMBINED THE MOST RESTRICTIVE\n CONDITIONS APPLY\n -\n -\n B-AFTER DEPARTURE-\n THE ITINERARY MUST BE RE-PRICED USING HISTORICAL\n FARES IN EFFECT ON THE ORIGINAL TICKETING DATE.\n THE NEW ITINERARY MUST MEET ALL THE RULE\n PROVISIONS OF THE NEWLY TICKETED FARES SUCH THAT\n THE RECALCULATED FARE COULD HAVE BEEN USED FOR\n THE NEW ITINERARY IF PURCHASED ON THE ORIGINAL\n TICKET ISSUE DATE\n -\n CHARGE APPLIES PER TRANSACTION - PER PERSON FOR\n ADULT CHILD AND INFANT WITH SEAT.\n INFANTS WITHOUT A SEAT ARE NOT CHARGED THE FEE\n -\n FOR TR DOMESTIC SECTORS- WITHOUT CHARGE\n -\n NEW FARE MAY BE EQUAL OR HIGHER. WHEN THE NEW\n ITINERARY RESULTS IN A HIGHER\n FARE THE DIFFERENCE WILL BE COLLECTED AND THE\n CHANGE FEE WILL BE APPLIED.\n -\n CHARGES SHALL NOT BE WAIVED FOR MEDICAL\n REASON\n -\n WHEN FARES ARE COMBINED THE MOST RESTRICTIVE\n CONDITIONS APPLY\n -\n -\n NOTE-\n SEQUENTIAL USE OF FLIGHT COUPONS - THIS FARE IS\n ONLY VALID IF THE FLIGHTS ARE TAKEN IN THE BOOKED\n SEQUENCE. OTHERWISE THE FARE WILL BE RECALCULATED\n BASED ON THE ACTUAL FLIGHT ROUTING.\n --\n\n CHANGES/CANCELLATIONS\n\n ANY TIME\n CHARGE USD 100.00 FOR NO-SHOW.\n NOTE -\n ---------\n CHARGES SHALL NOT BE WAIVED FOR MEDICAL REASON\n ---------\n CHILD DISCOUNT DOES NOT APPLY\n INFANT WITHOUT SEAT FREE OF CHARGE\n WHEN FARES ARE COMBINED THE MOST RESTRICTIVE\n CONDITIONS APPLY\n\n CANCELLATIONS\n\n BEFORE DEPARTURE\n CHARGE USD 50.00 FOR CANCEL/REFUND.\n NOTE -\n ANY TIME-\n -\n CHARGES SHALL NOT BE WAIVED FOR MEDICAL REASON\n --\n WHEN COMBINING FARES THE MOST RESTRICTIVE\n CANCELLATION CONDITIONS APPLY FOR THE ENTIRE\n PRICING UNIT\n ---\n CHILD DISCOUNT DOES NOT APPLY\n INFANT WITHOUT SEAT FREE OF CHARGE\n\n AFTER DEPARTURE\n CANCELLATIONS PERMITTED FOR CANCEL/REFUND.\n NOTE -\n FOR CANCELLATIONS AFTER DEPARTURE THE REFUND GIVEN\n WILL BE THE DIFFERENCE BETWEEN THE FARE PAID AND\n THE APPLICAPLE FARE FOR THE JOURNEY FLOWN.\n APPLICABLE FARE FOR THE JOURNEY FLOWN IS THE ONE\n THAT SET AT THE SAME RBD WITH THE ORIGINAL FARE\n PAID.\n IF NO FARE EXISTS FOR THE FLOWN JOURNEY\n ON THE SAME RBD WITH THE ORGINALFARE\n ANY FARE SET ON A HIGHER RBD WILL BE ACCEPTED.\n -----------------------------------\n WHEN FARES ARE COMBINED THE MOST RESTRICTIVE\n CONDITIONS APPLY'}}}}}, 'FlightMiniRules': 'null', 'PriceMessageInfo': {'PriceMessageInfo': {'MiniRulesPriceMessages': {'Text': 'null'}}}, 'PNRRemarks': {'PNRRemark': [{'@RemarkType': 'RM', '@RemarkCategory': '', '@Note': 'MEMBER_NAME:FirstName LastName'}, {'@RemarkType': 'RM', '@RemarkCategory': 'D', '@Note': 'DELIVERY TYPE: BookingOnly'}, {'@RemarkType': 'RM', '@RemarkCategory': 'A', '@Note': 'PORTAL: WSLACHIN'}, {'@RemarkType': 'RM', '@RemarkCategory': 'E', '@Note': 'FARE: 569.04 TRY'}, {'@RemarkType': 'RM', '@RemarkCategory': 'G', '@Note': 'PAYMENT TYPE: DEFAULT'}, {'@RemarkType': 'RC', '@RemarkCategory': '', '@Note': 'FLIGHT ADT TICKETFEE:TRY 569.04'}, {'@RemarkType': 'RM', '@RemarkCategory': '', '@Note': 'ASF FLIGHT TOTAL:TRY 569.04'}, {'@RemarkType': 'RM', '@RemarkCategory': '', '@Note': 'ASF PNR TOTAL:TRY 569.04'}, {'@RemarkType': 'RM', '@RemarkCategory': 'S', '@Note': 'SPECREQERR:INVALID TEXT DATA Type:DOCS P- 1002247-T12312233- 1002247-02MAY96-F-03APR18-FF-DD//H'}, {'@RemarkType': 'RM', '@RemarkCategory': 'S', '@Note': 'SPECREQERR:INVALID TEXT DATA Type:DOCO -V-1234567891236--- 1002247'}, {'@RemarkType': 'RC', '@RemarkCategory': '', '@Note': 'PRICING COMMANDFXP/R,UP,FC-TRY,VC-TK,THR.THR/LI/ET'}]}}, 'Success': 'null', '_id': ObjectId('5ac35d9fe138231d26bae955')}
```

delete json._id;
console.log(json);

Comment: Please add more context and format your question properly.

Comment: And this is not JSON.

Comment: if you add this code without '_id' field in https://www.freeformatter.com/json-formatter.html#ad-output  you will see the  json . by  '_id' it will be error. i want to remove it

Comment: Again: "Please add more context". Based on your question, we do not even know what programming language you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple call `delete a._id`

## Demo:

```js
let json = {
    "@Version": "0",
    "AirReservation": {
        "AirItinerary": {
            "OriginDestinationOptions": {
                "OriginDestinationOption": {
                    "@RefNumber": "0",
                    "@DirectionId": "0",
                    "@ElapsedTime": "0320",
                    "FlightSegment": {
                        "@DepartureDateTime": "2018-04-09T05:30:00",
                        "@ArrivalDateTime": "2018-04-09T07:20:00",
                        "@FlightNumber": "873",
                        "@ResBookDesigCode": "V",
                        "@Status": "HK",
                        "FlightDuration": "2018-04-03T03:20:00",
                        "DepartureAirport": {
                            "@LocationCode": "IKA",
                            "@Terminal": ""
                        },
                        "ArrivalAirport": {
                            "@LocationCode": "IST",
                            "@Terminal": "I"
                        },
                        "OperatingAirline": {
                            "@Code": "TK"
                        },
                        "Equipment": {
                            "@AirEquipType": "332"
                        },
                        "MarketingAirline": {
                            "@Code": "TK"
                        },
                        "BookingClassAvails": {
                            "BookingClassAvail": {
                                "@ResBookDesigCode": "V",
                                "@ResBookDesigQuantity": "9",
                                "@RPH": "ADT",
                                "@AvailablePTC": "ADT",
                                "@ResBookDesigCabinCode": "M",
                                "@FareBasis": "VLY1PXOW"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "PriceInfo": {
            "ItinTotalFare": {
                "BaseFare": {
                    "@Currency": "TRY",
                    "@Amount": "521.00"
                },
                "MarkupFare": {
                    "@Amount": "0"
                },
                "TotalFare": {
                    "@Amount": "569.04",
                    "@Currency": "TRY"
                },
                "TotalAmountInTicketingCurrency": {
                    "@Amount": "569.04",
                    "@Currency": "TRY"
                }
            },
            "PTC_FareBreakdowns": {
                "PTC_FareBreakdown": {
                    "PassengerTypeQuantity": {
                        "@Code": "ADT",
                        "@Quantity": "1"
                    },
                    "PassengerFare": {
                        "BaseFare": {
                            "@Amount": "521.00"
                        },
                        "MarkupFare": {
                            "@Amount": "0"
                        },
                        "Taxes": {
                            "Tax": {
                                "@Amount": "48.04"
                            }
                        },
                        "TotalFare": {
                            "@Amount": "569.04"
                        }
                    },
                    "TicketDesignators": {
                        "TicketDesignator": [
                            {
                                "@TicketDesignatorCode": "70|PEN",
                                "@TicketDesignatorExtension": "TICKETS ARE NON-REFUNDABLE|"
                            },
                            {
                                "@TicketDesignatorCode": "41|LTD",
                                "@TicketDesignatorExtension": "LAST TKT DTE|09APR18| - DATE OF ORIGIN|"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            "ServiceFees": {
                "ServiceFee": {
                    "@Amount": "0",
                    "@MarkupFeeAmount": "0",
                    "PassengerTypeQuantity": {
                        "@Code": "ADT",
                        "@Quantity": "1"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "TravelerInfo": {
            "AirTraveler": {
                "@PassengerTypeCode": "ADT",
                "NumberOfBaggages": "0",
                "NumberOfBaggages1": "0",
                "HandLuggages": "0",
                "HandLuggages1": "0",
                "PersonName": {
                    "NamePrefix": "MRS",
                    "GivenName": "dd",
                    "Surname": "ff"
                },
                "Telephone": {
                    "@PhoneType": "Home",
                    "@LocationCode": "_+98091_2366554"
                },
                "Email": "testss@gmail.com",
                "Document": [
                    {
                        "@DocID": "T12312233",
                        "@DocType": "DOCS",
                        "@InnerDocType": "Passport",
                        "@ExpireDate": "2018-04-03",
                        "@DocIssueCountry": " 1002247"
                    },
                    {
                        "@DocIssueLocation": "",
                        "@DocID": "1234567891236",
                        "@DocType": "DOCO",
                        "@DocIssueCountry": " 1002247"
                    },
                    {
                        "@DocType": "DOCA",
                        "@DocIssueCountry": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "@DocType": "DOCA2",
                        "@DocIssueCountry": ""
                    }
                ],
                "BirthDate": "1996-05-02"
            }
        },
        "Fulfillment": {
            "PaymentDetails": {
                "PaymentDetail": {
                    "@PaymentType": "None",
                    "@PaymentFPType": "FPCA",
                    "BillingAddress": {
                        "AddressLine": "hbuyh hjgb hj hjgyg",
                        "CityName": "Tehran",
                        "CountryName": {
                            "@Code": "IR"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "DeliveryAddress": {
                "AddressLine": "Iran Tehran",
                "CityName": "Tehran",
                "CountryName": {
                    "@Code": "IR"
                }
            }
        },
        "Ticketing": {
            "@TicketTimeLimit": "2018-04-05T23:59:00",
            "@TicketType": "BookingOnly"
        },
        "BookingReferenceID": {
            "@Type": "F",
            "@ID_Context": "QKC86K"
        },
        "FlightRulePenalties": {
            "FareRuleInfo": {
                "FareReference": "VLY1PXOW",
                "FilingAirline": {
                    "@Code": "TK"
                },
                "MarketingAirline": {
                    "@Code": "TK"
                },
                "DepartureAirport": {
                    "@LocationCode": "THR"
                },
                "ArrivalAirport": {
                    "@LocationCode": "IST"
                },
                "FareRules": {
                    "SubSection": {
                        "@SubTitle": "PENALTIES",
                        "@SubCode": "PE",
                        "Paragraph": {
                            "Text": "FOR ROUND TRIP INSTANT PURCHASE FARES\n\n CHANGES\n\n ANY TIME\n CHARGE USD 50.00 FOR REISSUE/REVALIDATION.\n NOTE -\n A-BEFORE DEPARTURE-\n ITINERARY MUST BE RE-PRICED USING CURRENT FARES\n IN EFFECT ON THE DATE THE TICKET IS REISSUED\n THE ITINERARY MUST MEET ALL RULE PROVISIONS OF\n THE NEWLY TICKETED FARE INCLUDING ADVANCE\n RESERVATION\n -\n CHARGE APPLIES PER TRANSACTION - PER PERSON FOR\n ADULT CHILD AND INFANT WITH SEAT.\n INFANTS WITHOUT A SEAT ARE NOT CHARGED THE FEE\n -\n FOR TR DOMESTIC SECTORS- WITHOUT CHARGE\n -\n NEW FARE MAY BE EQUAL OR HIGHER. WHEN THE NEW\n ITINERARY RESULTS IN A HIGHER\n FARE THE DIFFERENCE WILL BE COLLECTED AND THE\n CHANGE FEE WILL BE APPLIED.\n -\n CHARGES SHALL NOT BE WAIVED FOR MEDICAL\n REASON\n -\n WHEN FARES ARE COMBINED THE MOST RESTRICTIVE\n CONDITIONS APPLY\n -\n -\n B-AFTER DEPARTURE-\n THE ITINERARY MUST BE RE-PRICED USING HISTORICAL\n FARES IN EFFECT ON THE ORIGINAL TICKETING DATE.\n THE NEW ITINERARY MUST MEET ALL THE RULE\n PROVISIONS OF THE NEWLY TICKETED FARES SUCH THAT\n THE RECALCULATED FARE COULD HAVE BEEN USED FOR\n THE NEW ITINERARY IF PURCHASED ON THE ORIGINAL\n TICKET ISSUE DATE\n -\n CHARGE APPLIES PER TRANSACTION - PER PERSON FOR\n ADULT CHILD AND INFANT WITH SEAT.\n INFANTS WITHOUT A SEAT ARE NOT CHARGED THE FEE\n -\n FOR TR DOMESTIC SECTORS- WITHOUT CHARGE\n -\n NEW FARE MAY BE EQUAL OR HIGHER. WHEN THE NEW\n ITINERARY RESULTS IN A HIGHER\n FARE THE DIFFERENCE WILL BE COLLECTED AND THE\n CHANGE FEE WILL BE APPLIED.\n -\n CHARGES SHALL NOT BE WAIVED FOR MEDICAL\n REASON\n -\n WHEN FARES ARE COMBINED THE MOST RESTRICTIVE\n CONDITIONS APPLY\n -\n -\n NOTE-\n SEQUENTIAL USE OF FLIGHT COUPONS - THIS FARE IS\n ONLY VALID IF THE FLIGHTS ARE TAKEN IN THE BOOKED\n SEQUENCE. OTHERWISE THE FARE WILL BE RECALCULATED\n BASED ON THE ACTUAL FLIGHT ROUTING.\n --\n\n CHANGES/CANCELLATIONS\n\n ANY TIME\n CHARGE USD 100.00 FOR NO-SHOW.\n NOTE -\n ---------\n CHARGES SHALL NOT BE WAIVED FOR MEDICAL REASON\n ---------\n CHILD DISCOUNT DOES NOT APPLY\n INFANT WITHOUT SEAT FREE OF CHARGE\n WHEN FARES ARE COMBINED THE MOST RESTRICTIVE\n CONDITIONS APPLY\n\n CANCELLATIONS\n\n BEFORE DEPARTURE\n CHARGE USD 50.00 FOR CANCEL/REFUND.\n NOTE -\n ANY TIME-\n -\n CHARGES SHALL NOT BE WAIVED FOR MEDICAL REASON\n --\n WHEN COMBINING FARES THE MOST RESTRICTIVE\n CANCELLATION CONDITIONS APPLY FOR THE ENTIRE\n PRICING UNIT\n ---\n CHILD DISCOUNT DOES NOT APPLY\n INFANT WITHOUT SEAT FREE OF CHARGE\n\n AFTER DEPARTURE\n CANCELLATIONS PERMITTED FOR CANCEL/REFUND.\n NOTE -\n FOR CANCELLATIONS AFTER DEPARTURE THE REFUND GIVEN\n WILL BE THE DIFFERENCE BETWEEN THE FARE PAID AND\n THE APPLICAPLE FARE FOR THE JOURNEY FLOWN.\n APPLICABLE FARE FOR THE JOURNEY FLOWN IS THE ONE\n THAT SET AT THE SAME RBD WITH THE ORIGINAL FARE\n PAID.\n IF NO FARE EXISTS FOR THE FLOWN JOURNEY\n ON THE SAME RBD WITH THE ORGINALFARE\n ANY FARE SET ON A HIGHER RBD WILL BE ACCEPTED.\n -----------------------------------\n WHEN FARES ARE COMBINED THE MOST RESTRICTIVE\n CONDITIONS APPLY"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "FlightMiniRules": "null",
        "PriceMessageInfo": {
            "PriceMessageInfo": {
                "MiniRulesPriceMessages": {
                    "Text": "null"
                }
            }
        },
        "PNRRemarks": {
            "PNRRemark": [
                {
                    "@RemarkType": "RM",
                    "@RemarkCategory": "",
                    "@Note": "MEMBER_NAME:FirstName LastName"
                },
                {
                    "@RemarkType": "RM",
                    "@RemarkCategory": "D",
                    "@Note": "DELIVERY TYPE: BookingOnly"
                },
                {
                    "@RemarkType": "RM",
                    "@RemarkCategory": "A",
                    "@Note": "PORTAL: WSLACHIN"
                },
                {
                    "@RemarkType": "RM",
                    "@RemarkCategory": "E",
                    "@Note": "FARE: 569.04 TRY"
                },
                {
                    "@RemarkType": "RM",
                    "@RemarkCategory": "G",
                    "@Note": "PAYMENT TYPE: DEFAULT"
                },
                {
                    "@RemarkType": "RC",
                    "@RemarkCategory": "",
                    "@Note": "FLIGHT ADT TICKETFEE:TRY 569.04"
                },
                {
                    "@RemarkType": "RM",
                    "@RemarkCategory": "",
                    "@Note": "ASF FLIGHT TOTAL:TRY 569.04"
                },
                {
                    "@RemarkType": "RM",
                    "@RemarkCategory": "",
                    "@Note": "ASF PNR TOTAL:TRY 569.04"
                },
                {
                    "@RemarkType": "RM",
                    "@RemarkCategory": "S",
                    "@Note": "SPECREQERR:INVALID TEXT DATA Type:DOCS P- 1002247-T12312233- 1002247-02MAY96-F-03APR18-FF-DD//H"
                },
                {
                    "@RemarkType": "RM",
                    "@RemarkCategory": "S",
                    "@Note": "SPECREQERR:INVALID TEXT DATA Type:DOCO -V-1234567891236--- 1002247"
                },
                {
                    "@RemarkType": "RC",
                    "@RemarkCategory": "",
                    "@Note": "PRICING COMMANDFXP/R,UP,FC-TRY,VC-TK,THR.THR/LI/ET"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "Success": "null",
    "_id": "ObjectId(\"5ac35d9fe138231d26bae955\")"
};


delete json._id;

console.log(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the **delete** operator. Delete will remove a given property from an object.

[View an example here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

Currently I don't have the tools available to try it myself, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557580/how-to-return-the-objectid-or-id-of-an-document-in-mongodb-and-error-in-need?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) is a similar question that might help you out, if you are unable to delete it.

If you still have issues after trying the two methods above, I recommend asking the question: 'How to access property id's and values in this object', since the object you posted seems a bit hard to parse.

Good luck!

Comment: i have already tried this code, but doesn't work.  var key = "_id";
  for (var key in someObj) {
    if (someObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       delete someObj[key];
    }
}

Comment: Checkout @Kristianmitk 's answer, seems like it worked for him

Comment: @Kristianmitk 's answer worked , but my code doesn't look like answer 's code. my code :'_id': ObjectId('5ac35d9fe138231d26bae955') answer 's code:"_id": "ObjectId(\"5ac35d9fe138231d26bae955\")" . i don't why it doesnt work??