# How to slice the first object in the Array JS

Tags: javascript

I have an array containing objects :

```
userFromDb [
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("62d54652982bed4574869188"),
    userName: 'adi',
    password: '1234'
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("62d54747982bed457486919f"),
    userName: 'an',
    password: '12345'
  }
]
```

I need to edit the _id in JS. This is the desired output:

```
userFromDb [
  {
    _id:'62d54652982bed4574869188',
    userName: 'adi',
    password: '1234'
  },
  {
    _id:'62d54747982bed457486919f',
    userName: 'an',
    password: '12345'
  }
]
```

I tried :

```
let userFromDb2 = userFromDb.map(x => x._id.slice(12))
```

And I got an error

```
TypeError: x._id.slice is not a function
```

Someone knows how to do it?

Comment: You don't want to "slice" anything, you want to get the value from a (presumably MongoDB) ObjectId.

Comment: Can you provide more information on your `ObjectID` class? How do you get the ID string from the object?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on structure of `ObjectId` class 
for expample

```
class ObjectId {
    constructor(id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

in this class you can easily get id like this

```
let userFromDb2 = userFromDb.map(x => x._id.id)
```

and if you are using mongoDB this may help you
[this may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557580/how-to-return-the-objectid-or-id-of-an-document-in-mongodb-and-error-in-need)

Answer (score -1):

You should specify the start and  number of characters to cut in the string.
so syntax
let userFromDb2 = userFromDb.map(x => x._id.slice(0,12))
Hope this would help